# Scaling high resolution image before sending it to apple watch in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, apple-watch

In my app, i want to scale my image which is being sent to apple watch because in simulator there's no problem but when sending from real device, payload size limits comes in action. I also want to know how much payload the apple watch can take when using send message method while using watch connectivity.

source code for my watch app:

```
    class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session: WCSession!

    var MessageData = NSMutableDictionary()

    @IBOutlet var watch_displayImage: WKInterfaceImage!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticket_category: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticketType: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticketTime: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticketDate: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        if WCSession.isSupported()
        {

            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()

        }

    }

    override func willActivate()
    {

        super.willActivate()

    }

    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
    {

        //print(message.values)

        MessageData = NSMutableDictionary(object: message, forKey: "data")
        print("\(MessageData)")
        watch_ticket_category.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["ticket_category"] as! String)")
        watch_displayImage.setImage(UIImage(named: MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["imagePath"] as! String))
        watch_ticketType.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["ticket_type"] as! String)")
        watch_ticketTime.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["time"] as! String)")
        watch_ticketDate.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["date"] as! String)")


   }
```

source code for my IOS app:

```
    class TicketDetailViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {
  let dic1  = NSMutableDictionary()
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
    var databasePath = NSString()
    var holding_Ticket_category: String = ""
    var holding_Image: UIImage?
    var hold_ticketName: String = ""
    var hold_ticketDate: String = ""
    var hold_ticketTime: String = ""
    var session: WCSession!
    var imageData: NSData!

    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_grey: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cropped_frame: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var display_image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_type_name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_category: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported(){
            self.session  = WCSession.defaultSession()
            self.session.delegate = self
            self.session.activateSession()
        }

        defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        display_image.image = self.holding_Image
        ticket_type_name.text = hold_ticketName
        ticket_date.text = hold_ticketDate
        ticket_time.text = hold_ticketTime
        ticket_category.text = holding_Ticket_category

        let filemgr =  NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
        var ticketDB: FMDatabase

        databasePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("ticket_Pass.sqlite")


        if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String)
        {

            ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
            if ticketDB.open()
            {

                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGEPATH TEXT, IMAGENAME TEXT, TICKET_CATEGORY TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                ticketDB.close()
            } else
            {
                 print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
        }else{
            ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
            if ticketDB.open()
            {

                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGEPATH TEXT, IMAGENAME TEXT, TICKET_CATEGORY TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                ticketDB.close()
            } else
            {

                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }

        }
    }

    func saveImageToFolder()
    {

        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(holding_Image!)!
        let imageName = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()).png"
        let imagePath = (self.getDocumentsDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
        print("imagePath:- \(imagePath)")
        print("image size: \(holding_Image?.size)")

        imageData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imagePath, forKey: "ImagePath")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageData, forKey: "ImageData")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageName, forKey: "ImageName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String{
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0]
        print("document path:- \(documentsPath)")
        return documentsPath

    }

  @IBAction func addTickets(sender: UIButton)
  {

        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {
                //self.saveImageToFolder()
                let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (imagePath, imageName, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagePath")!)', '\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageName")!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

                let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                if !result
                {

                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                } else
                {

                    let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved to Database!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

                    alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

                    }))

                    self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print(databasePath)

               }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func deleteTickets(sender: UIButton) {
        let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Delete Ticket Details!", description: "Are you sure?", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

        alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: PMAlertActionStyle.Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }))
        alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK", style: PMAlertActionStyle.Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func sendToWatch(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {
            self.saveImageToFolder()
            let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (imagePath, imageName, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagePath")!)', '\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageName")!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

            let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if !result
            {

                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

            } else
            {

                let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

                alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action:
                { (ACTION) -> Void in


                        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: self.databasePath as String)
                        if ticketDB.open()
                        {

//                            let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
                             let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET "

                            let result: FMResultSet? = ticketDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                            if let result = result
                            {

                                let ticketDataArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                                while result.next()
                                {

                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("imagePath"), forKey: "imagePath")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("imageName"), forKey: "imageName")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_category"), forKey: "ticket_category")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_type"), forKey: "ticket_type")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("date"), forKey: "date")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("time"), forKey: "time")

                                    ticketDataArray.addObject(self.dic1)

                                }
                                print("ticketDataArray :  \(self.dic1)")
                            }else
                            {
                                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                            }

                          ticketDB.close()

                        }
                      self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                        if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable
                        {
                            let dict = ["Watchdat":self.dic1]

                            self.session.sendMessage(dict, replyHandler: { (replayDic: [String:AnyObject]) in
                                print("success!")
                                }, errorHandler: { (error:NSError) in
                                    print("error")
                            })
                        }

                }))

                self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print(databasePath)

            }
        }
```

[image: screenshot for my app]

Comment: What have you tried so far to realize the scaling? Where exactly is your problem when scaling? Please don't expect people to implement scaling in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

We scale using a max pixel approach. You can try to re-size until desired threshold is met

```
#define MAX_PIXEL_SIZE 800


CGImageRef createScreenShotWithRestrectedSize(NSData * screenShotData, int maxPixelSize)
{
    CGImageRef        myScreenShot = NULL;
    CGImageSourceRef  myImageSource;
    CFDictionaryRef   myOptions = NULL;
    CFStringRef       myKeys[3];
    CFTypeRef         myValues[3];
    CFNumberRef       screenShotMaxPixelSize;

    myImageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)screenShotData,
                                                NULL);

    if (myImageSource == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Image source is NULL.");
        return  NULL;
    }

    screenShotMaxPixelSize = CFNumberCreate(NULL, kCFNumberIntType, &maxPixelSize);

    //Create image options:
    // 0: Allow image transformation (rescale and oriantation)
    myKeys[0] = kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform;
    myValues[0] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;
    // 1: Always create a Thumbnail, even if the image has one
    myKeys[1] = kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways;
    myValues[1] = (CFTypeRef)kCFBooleanTrue;
    // 2: Set height and width maxPixel size
    myKeys[2] = kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize;
    myValues[2] = (CFTypeRef)screenShotMaxPixelSize;

    myOptions = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **) myKeys,
                                   (const void **) myValues, 3,
                                   &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                   & kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    // Create image with above options
    myScreenShot = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(myImageSource,
                                                           0,
                                                           myOptions);

    // Release resources
    CFRelease(screenShotMaxPixelSize);
    CFRelease(myOptions);
    CFRelease(myImageSource);

    // Make sure the thumbnail image exists before continuing.
    if (myScreenShot == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Screen shot image does not exists");
        return NULL;
    }

    return myScreenShot;
}

NSData *dataCapturedScreen = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,1);

    //Create an image that will have a 60kb size restriction
CGImageRef ir = createScreenShotWithRestrectedSize(dataCapturedScreen, MAX_PIXEL_SIZE);
UIImage *restrictedSizeImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ir];
CGImageRelease(ir);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(restrictedSizeImage, 0.5);
```